# Image data not registering

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new to developing a **wordpress plugin** and in using PHP as a whole. But I have built a functional plugin.

Problem :
I can't seem to register data for an image that is uploaded in my plugin.

Here's my code:

```
<?php foreach( $tiles as $tile ): ?>
    <?php 
        $tile_img = get_post_meta( $tile->ID, 'artise-tile-img', true );
        $category_terms = implode( ', ', get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy'              => 'artise-tile-category',
            'object_ids'            => $tile->ID,
            'fields'                => 'names'
        ) ) );
        $itile = array_search( $tile->ID, $curr_tile_ids );
        $tileExists = true;
        if( $itile === false ){
            $itile =  $tile_count;
            $tileExists = false;
            $curr_tile_ids []= $tile->ID;
        }
    ?>
    <div 
        class="tile-image-container tile-image-cointainer-<?php echo $tile_count ?>" 
        data-tile-id="<?php echo $tile->ID ?>"
        data-itile="<?php echo $itile ?>"
        data-tile-name="<?php echo htmlentities( $tile->post_title ) ?>"
        data-tile-desc="<?php echo htmlentities( $tile->post_excerpt ) ?>"
        data-category="<?php echo $category_terms ?>"
        data-category-slug="<?php echo $tile_category->slug ?>"
    >
        <img src="<?php echo $tile_img ?>" data-shape="" data-is-hex="" width="75" height="75">
        <?php echo $tile->post_title ?>
    </div>
    ?>
```

The codes above are on a php file that will register a "tile" inside my plugin. On a separate php file that's supposedly be able to place the tile info, I have these codes:

```
<div 
class="tile-image-container tile-image-cointainer-<?php echo $tile_count ?>" 
data-tile-id="<?php echo $tile->ID ?>"
data-itile="<?php echo $itile ?>"
data-tile-name="<?php echo htmlentities( $tile->post_title ) ?>"
data-tile-desc="<?php echo htmlentities( $tile->post_excerpt ) ?>"
data-category="<?php echo $category_terms ?>"
data-category-slug="<?php echo $tile_category->slug ?>"
>
<img src="<?php echo $tile_img ?>" data-shape="" data-is-hex="" width="75" height="75"><?php echo $tile->post_title ?>
```

How come these data are not outputted when I do an "inspect element on the actual page as seen on the image below:

Output on webpage:

[image]

Comment: Hi Wendz. The code you posted isn't nearly enough for us to help you debug it (eg. where does `$tile_img` come from?) Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: cabrerahector- thanks for the heads up. I edited the first code which indicates where the $tile_img is being pulled from.

Comment: _“How come these data are not outputted”_ - which ones exactly? The only empty one I can see in your screenshot, that presumably should have a value, is `data-tile-desc` - and if that stays empty, well then most likely no proper excerpt was set for your item in the backend to begin with.

Comment: The one highlighted on the attached image was what I was referring to. data-shape and data-is-hex to be specific

Comment: Well you have `data-shape="" data-is-hex=""` in the PHP code you have shown in that place … so what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Oh shoot! That one's blank! Therefore not pulling data! Thanks for pointing that out! I'm supposed to pull the data from a custom metabox.